# Parse XML with regards to one namespace only

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I need to parse XML files with regards to only one namespace.

By "with regards to only one namespace" I mean that if I have document like this:

```
<xc:document xmlns:xc="asdasd">
  <asdf>
    <xc:abcd />
  </asdf>
</xc:document>
```

I would like `<asdf>`, `</asdf>` to be treated as text.

The structure of this document should look like this:

```
document
|
|- text (<asdf>)
|- abcd
|- text (</asdf>)
```

What is the simplest method to achieve this?

Comment: You realize then that this isn't really XML? All angle brackets count as tags, if they are to be treated as text, they need to be an entity, or they should be in cdata blocks?

Answer (score 3):

Transform the document with xslt first so that the nodes you want treated as text actually are text.

Comment: Nice idea, but the whole problem is that I need to parse the file like this: nodes that are in my namespace should be transformed and then written to the output, and the rest just needs to be written to the output.

Comment: Just transform three times. First, some nodes become text. Second, remaining nodes transform as desired. Third, text nodes transformation back to element nodes.

Comment: It sounds to me like you don't want text nodes at all. You just want to transform nodes in one namespace but pass through nodes in all other namespaces. I don't know enough about xslt to say how, but I'm sure this can be done. You might want to ask that question more directly and tag it xslt.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any XML parser is going to lose distinctions like whether single or double quotes were used, or CDATA sections were used, or whitespace inside tags (not between tags).

So:
    <boy    socks="black"
    ></boy>
might come back as <boy socks='black'/>

If you want to treat the input as not XML, you'll have to fall back on non-XML tools, *or* rethink your situation entirely, as this is a very unusual thing to want to do.

It's fairly easy in a text-processing language such as Perl, if you are careful. For example,

```
perl -p -e 's#<(/?[^:]+[\s>])#\&lt;$1#g'
```

will go a long way, by changing the < signs you want to treat as text into &lt; instead. This approach actually works best if you read the whole file in Perl rather than (as in this example) a line at a time, so that you can match close tags spread over multiple lines,

```
</boy
> like this.
```

But, best to parse XML with an XML parser, not regular expressions, so if the sort of changes I mentioned above are OK, this is really easy to do in XSLT.

Comment: Using a regular expression on an input language which is not regular is a mistake. XML is not a regular language.

Comment: As I said, yes, don't do that. On the other hand the subset of well-formed XML consisting of elements without CDATA sections or comments can be pre-processed as I showed, if the poster really insists on treating it in a non-XML way.  There's a fabulous answer about not using regular expressions to parse XML of course...

Comment: I'm thinking now about using pull parser (something like KXML i java) to do this. Pull parser is not a DOM parser - it's going to give me the information about opening tag as well as closing tag and not just the structure.

Comment: There's a simpler solution.. Using XMLReader I can do whatever I want!

Comment: No - with XMLReader you'll lose the distinction between double and single quotes round attribute values for example. If the purpose is to be able to use tools like "diff" then you have to use non-XML processing to some extent. But if (as I hope) you can live with those changes then yes, use XMLReader and serialize those element back out unchanged, or (even easier) use XSLT.